# Variável de sessão não está sendo criada

Tags: php

Estou criando um redirecionamento, vindo de um *link* de *email*, para o usuário acessar o tal *link*, URL.
Porém, o problema é que não estou conseguindo setar a sessão para essa URL!
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código como está:

**logon.php:**

```
if (isset($_POST["login"])){
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$tabela_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE owner_email='$email' AND password='$password' ";

$resul = mysql_query($tabela_usuarios);

$regs = mysql_num_rows($resul);

if ($regs <> 0){
    $owner_id = mysql_result($resul, 0, "owner_id");
    $userName = mysql_result($resul, 0, "owner_firstName");

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['owner_id'] = $owner_id;
    $_SESSION['owner_firstName'] = $userName;

if(isset($_SESSION['redirectURL'])) {

  $url = $_SESSION['redirectURL'];

  unset($_SESSION['redirectURL']);
  header("Location: ".$url);
} else {
  header("Location: default.php");
}
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.html");
}
}
```

**Código de validação de login:**

```
include_once("con/conexao.php");
session_start();

$owner_id = $_SESSION['owner_id'];
$userName = $_SESSION['owner_firstName'];

if($userName == ""){
   $_SESSION['redirectURL'] = "TESTANDO!!!";
   var_dump($_SESSION);
   //header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

Comment: Apresenta algum erro?

Comment: Não @AndréBaill.
Dou um var_dump e ela não aparece... Somente as outras duas owner_id e iserName.

Comment: Tenta inserir o session_start no começo do arquivo.

Comment: Mas já está no começo do arquivo, @André Baill... Ou eu não te entendi.

Comment: Remova `session_start();` do meio do seu código e coloque na primeira linha de execução, logo após a abertura da tag do php: `<?php session_start();`

Comment: Foi o que eu disse @KaduAmaral :) É a mesma situação. colocar o session_start() no começo do arquivo, porque no meio nunca funciona.. ao menos comigo, nunca deu certo!

Comment: Alterei e continua aparecendo NULL, no var_dump.

Comment: @AndréBaill, tirei o session_start de onde estava e passei para a primeira linha.
Nada mudou.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, tens outra sugestão?

Comment: Algum erro é exibido? Habilite os erros `ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);` para ter certeza que não...